# How do I use PHP's str_replace() to generate multiple form checkboxes from multiple strings?

Tags: php, html, str-replace

I know how to use str_replace(), but this is just beyond me. Here's the input (would come from a MySQL query):

```
[%] This is a checkbox
[%] I have seen "Star Trek VI: The Voyage Home"
[%] I'm a geek
```

Here's how I would like the output rendered:

```
<label><input type="checkbox" name="requirement[1]" value="1">This is a checkbox</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="requirement[2]" value="1">I have seen "Star Trek VI: The Voyage Home"</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="requirement[3]" value="1">I'm a geek</label>
```

Obviously, having the [%] at the beginning of the line would denote it becoming a checkbox as would being on separate lines (unless there's a better, user-friendly way). **If there's a better way than using str_replace(), I'd love to know.**

*Thanks in advance!*

Comment: Yes, investigate [regular expressions](http://regexp.info/) and [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/preg_replace), which avoids many tedious string operations.

Comment: @mario I don't see how preg_replace works better here than str_replace. Please post an answer if you know, I'm interested!

Comment: Admittedly, my understanding of regular expressions is very weak. :(

Comment: @Luc It can save the loop by matching `^` line start and `$` end. You also don't need a manual index counter, as PHP accepts input params ala `<input name="requirements[]">` and builds an array itself. A regex is preferrable if you want to assert the input format. But obviously, your snippet works just as well for this simple case. I just prefer one-liners.

Comment: @mario I'm trying your suggestion but can't get it to work. Could you have a look what I'm doing wrong in [the example I posted](http://lucb1e.com/rp/crapware/replacething.php)?

Comment: @Luc It's perfect, but you need to add the `/m` modfier, to set PCRE into multiline mode for `^` and `$`.

Comment: @mario Awesome, thank you! (Yes, I too like one-liners :).) I had already looked at possible modifiers, but thought this wouldn't do what I wanted. Next time I'll just try it ^^.

Since this is actually another solution, do you want to post it?

Comment: You guys both rawk! Thank you kindly for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$lines = explode("\n", $mysql_result_string);
$n = 0;
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    echo str_replace('[%]', '<label><input type="checkbox" name="requirement[' . $n . ']" value="1">', $line) . "</label>";
    $n++;
}
```

Edit: Yup: [example here](http://lucb1e.com/rp/crapware/replacething.php).